# Can't Change Background of UIButton ios

Tags: ios

When a user clicks on UIButton that has background image that i put from storyboard  , it will display a UIActionSheet letting the user to choose from the options:

1) Take a picture from camera

2) Picture from gallery photos.

If for example, he chooses to pick a picture from gallery photos, when he selects an image and returns to the view and display the image , i want to change the background image of the UIButton to another one that i want to put it programatically.

Here is the code of the ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate> {
UIImageView * imageView;
UIToolbar *toolbar ;

}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *ButtonPicture;@property (weak,  nonatomic) IBOutlet UIToolbar *toolbar;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView * imageView;

- (IBAction)PictureButton:(UIButton *)sender;


@end
```

Here is the code of ViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)PictureButton:(UIButton *)sender {   
NSLog(@"Click button take picture in toolbar view 1");

UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Photo" 
                                                         delegate:self
                                                cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                           destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                otherButtonTitles:@"Picture From Camera", @"Picture From Gallery", nil];
[actionSheet setTag:1001];
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
}

-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
switch (buttonIndex)
{
    case 0: {
        // Take a picture from camera
        UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    }
    break;
    case 1: {
        // take a picture from gallery photos

        UIImagePickerController * picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
        [self.view addSubview:toolbar];
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    }
    break;
    }

    -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    UIImage *gotImage =
    [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
[PictureButton setBackgroundImage:gotImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

}

When i select an image from Library , i return to the view , i display the image that i selected but the UIBUtton Background won't change to another background.
 Thanks

Comment: what is `PictureButton`? where did you declare it ?

Comment: in "ViewController.h " i put it like this 
- (IBAction)PictureButton:(UIButton *)sender;

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
[ButtonPicture setBackgroundImage:gotImage forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: the fisrt background image name is background1.png i put it in Storyboard UIButton image settings and now i want to change the background of the background image to background2.png programatically when i select an image from library and return to the view

Answer (score 0):

This is `(IBAction)PictureButton:(UIButton *)sender;` method, you have wired up with your storyboard. As same as, you have to wired with `UIBarbuttonItam property` as. `ButtonPicture(not PictureButton)`. So you can try this.

```
-(void)changeImage:(UIImage*)newImage
{
      UIImage *configImage = newImage;
      UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, self.ButtonPicture.width, 32)];
      [btn setBackgroundImage:configImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      [btn addTarget:self.ButtonPicture.target action:self.ButtonPicture.action       forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
      self.ButtonPicture.customView = btn;
}
```

call this method instead of `[PictureButton setBackgroundImage:gotImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];`.

Answer (score 0):

on tapping which button does your action sheet get called?is it the  UIBarButtonItem *ButtonPicture? if yes then set the background image as `[ButtonPicture setBackgroundImage:gotImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];`